# “Shared” authentication for website and RESTful API

Tags: api, http, rest, authentication, restful-authentication

Goal: My server needs to direct non-users to a landing/home page, and logged in users to the actual app. When the app is loaded, it will make *authenticated* HTTP requests to a RESTful API (via Ajax).

I have a RESTful API that needs authentication. On another server I have my website, which also needs authentication, so I can determine whether to display the landing/home page for non-users or the app for logged in users.

Initially I thought it would be enough to implement HTTP Basic Auth for the RESTful API. However, in order to get authentication running for my website too, I would also need to setup authentication there, which would mean duplicating the low-level code to check the credentials in the database in both the REST API and the website servers.

Alternatively, I wondered if the website could authenticate via the RESTful API. For example, in my request handler for `POST /login`, I could make a `GET` request to my API, passing along the user credentials from the request body. If the request returns `200 OK`, I could sign the user’s session, thus authenticating them. From there onwards, the Ajax requests to the REST API need to be authenticated with the same credentials, so I could:

- set a cookie containing the credentials, thus allowing the JavaScript to retrieve the credentials before doing the request (OK with SSL?)
- dump the credentials in the served HTML for the web app thus allowing the JavaScript to retrieve the credentials before doing the request (OK with SSL?)
- proxy the API through the web app server, where I could retrieve the credentials from the session and add them to the `Authorization` header of the proxied request?

Alternatively, I imagine I could just share a session between the two servers, although I’ve heard that’s bad practice for RESTful design.

What would be wrong with doing it like this? Is there a better way to meet my goal?

Answer (score 3):

I recently implemented something similar to this (assuming I understand you correctly), and there seemed to be a few viable options.

- Have the server side of your web-app always authenticate with a specific username/password when accessing the REST API, ensuring that your web-app is always trusted and assuming that users are properly logged in on the web-app if a request is authenticated as the app.

  - Pros: Easy to implement, easy to understand, easy to extend for other applications as well (we had a CLI that accessed the same REST API as well).
  - Cons: It's impossible for the REST API to know which user is actually accessing it. If a trusted client is compromised the whole system is compromised.
- Have the server side of your web-app keep user details in the session and authenticate using the users credentials every time you access the REST API.

  - Pros: Fairly easy to implement (although some authentication mechanisms make it hard to keep hold of the user password - for good reason). The whole procedure is transparent to the REST API.
  - Cons: You're now storing (for all intents and purposes in clear-text) the username and password of a user in the session of the web-server - one of the most prime targets for attack in the system.
- Create an authentication system on the REST API that authenticates a request with a username/password authorization and returns a token that is valid for a limited time.

  - Pros: More secure, if your web-app is compromised you're not providing the attacker with your users username/passwords, but instead only allowing them a limited time access.
  - Cons: Much harder to implement. You might need to deal with token timeouts specifically. For purists it also means that your REST implementation (or at least the authentication system) will be arguably "stateful".

What you should implement would depend on your situation. Personally I'd definitely go with the more secure option (the last one), but due to external constraints we were forced to implement the first option in our specific case (with the promise we'd revisit it and upgrade later - unfortunately later never comes).

Comment: I understand the last two options, but not the first. Can you elaborate re-phrase how this would meet my goal, allowing a web app to be authenticated as well as Ajax requests directly to the API?

Comment: The web app would authenticate as any other client to the REST API, it would just have its own login details not related to any user. Without knowing your exact situation I can't really tell you whether it's a good option or not, although I'd generally avoid it - we did it primarily because of external pressure and the fact that we could not allow AJAX requests directly to the REST API (it was considered a security risk by the powers that be), so the web-app became something of a proxy for AJAX requests.

Comment: I don't get the "it would have its own login details" part. If the user needs to authenticate with the web app (to receive the app instead of the home page document), surely they will need to enter their username and password? There is where I was thinking of then sending off the entered credentials to the REST API. Once the user is authenticated with the web app, they would receive the app document and that could make authenticated requests to the API using the credentials stored in the session.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach with using Basic HTTP Authentication in REST service and having your app authenticate with the service is perfectly fine. The only caveat here (which I am sure you are aware of), is that your REST service should run over SSL, as Basic HTTP authentication is not very secure - username and password are just Base64 encoded.

Comment: What endpoint should I define on my API which the web app will make a request to? Would a simple `GET` to something like `/auth` be OK (defining the `Authorization` header in the request)?

Comment: That would be perfectly fine - then you can return 200 if the authentication was successful and 401 if not. I had a similar case, but I did it without dedicated auth call, basically from the login page I make a call to rest API to retrieve user with a specific username, passing username and password in authenticate header - then if the log-in fails I return 401, if the log-in succeeds I return 200 and the user resource (which is required by the app regardless - so it saves an extra call).

Comment: Np, the other useful thing is that even if you return 401 you can still return a response alongside, so you can for example pass the reason code and the message why the authentication failed, if you require more info.

Comment: Just thought — when the user authenticates and accesses the web app, how should I retrieve the username and password to send off with every Ajax request to the RESTful API? I guess I could store it in the website session and then dump it on the page for the JavaScript to read?

Comment: Or, store it in the session and then proxy the API through the web server, where I could retrieve the credentials from the session and pass them on as HTTP basic auth. This is all becoming very complex!

Comment: Keeping username in session and calling service server side would probably be easiest. That way you do not need to worry about CORS.

Comment: I would need to store the username and password in order to fill in the aurhorization headers when the browser makes a request directly to the API. Right?

Comment: Updated my answer to list the potential possibilities for authenticating the REST API calls.